# page reload and send post to himself

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have a php page that have `$id=$_GET['id'];` I want to make a select box that when you click on some option will reload the page (with the GET **+** a new value number in post).

I did that:

```
function test(){
    var id="<?= $id?>";
    $("#box").bind("change", function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/somepage.php?id='+id,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {f: val}
        });
    });
}
```

Now its don't do anything (or do and i dont see it..)

Comment: If you plan to reload the page, you don't need AJAX for this. Create your form, submit it to the PHP script, read the contents of `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` (depending on which method you specify in your form) and set the form appropriately.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload page then why do you need Ajax assuming $id is your $_GET['id'] do this

```
function test(){
var id="<?= $id?>";
$("#box").bind("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
      var newVal = parseInt(val)+parseInt(id);
       window.location.href='somepage.php?id='+newVal;
});
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of a Cross-Site-Scripting vulnerability :)

Comment: I really didn't understand what you did there. You just add the 2 values into 1 and sent it in get? I need to diffrent int.. Please explain what you did.